# How to replace an XElement value without changing the encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to replace the contents of an XElement with text that contains arbitrary strings including html comments, eg

```
<!-- an example goes here -->
<add key="SampleDetailsImporter.StartFolder" value="c:\temp" />
```

My code is

```
var section = configFile.Descendants(sectionToReplace).FirstOrDefault();
// Replace section if enabled and replacement supplied.
if (section!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacementString) && replaceEnabled)
{
    section.SetValue(replacementString);
}
```

where *replacementString* is something like

```
"<!-- an example goes here --> <add key=\"SampleDetailsImporter.StartFolder\" value=\"c:\temp\" />"
```

My problem is that after the replacement, all the < and > characters are encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt`;

I need the saved config file to look like this:

```
<MenuPlugins>
<!-- an example goes here --> 
<add key=\"SampleDetailsImporter.StartFolder\" value=\"c:\temp\" />
</MenuPlugins>
```

and not this:

```
<MenuPlugins>
&lt;!-- an example goes here --&gt; 
&lt;add key=\"SampleDetailsImporter.StartFolder\" value=\"c:\temp\" /&gt;
</MenuPlugins>
```

How can I overcome this? (I've tried applying the System.Web.HttpUtility.Decode or Encode methods - no improvement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to use

```
section.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(replacementString);
```

where *replacementString* includes the element tags.

Comment: If you use `ReplaceNodes` instead of `ReplaceWith`, you don't need to include the section tag in the replacement string, which it looks, from your question, like you don't already have in it.

Comment: But I do need to retain any xml comments in the replacementString value, which you say will be discarded. I need to replace the existing element with exactly the value of replacementString, and have embedded newlines (\n or &xA;) translated to line breaks in the XML when the config file is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the XmlDocument class, it should encode it in your desired way.

Comment: I'm already using the XDocument class to load the XML and Linq To XML to find the element of interest - what did you mean?

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(documentString);

with documentString as your whole xml and then

    doc.Save(filePath);

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
section.ReplaceNodes(XDocument.Parse(replacementString).Nodes());
```

It would always be my preference to avoid manipulating the XML fragment as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got there in the end using a mixture of Linq to XML and the 'old' Xml namespace:

```
        XDocument configFile = XDocument.Load(fileToSearch);
        var section = configFile.Descendants(sectionToReplace).FirstOrDefault();
        // Replace section if enabled and replacement supplied.
        if (section != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacementString))
        {
            section.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(replacementString.Replace(@"\n", "&#xA;")));
        }

            //save the amended file
            var newConfigFile = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            newConfigFile.LoadXml(configFile.ToString());
            newConfigFile.Save(fileToSearch);
```

There may still be improvements to be had in this code, but it's a once-off tool that now does the job so I'm going to leave it there. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick,

Maybe I have misunderstood, but my final code is as below (which doesn't seem to discard xml comments in the string value):

```
        var section = configFile.Descendants(sectionToReplace).FirstOrDefault();
        // Replace section if enabled and replacement supplied.
        if (section != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacementString) && replaceEnabled)
        {
            section.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(replacementString.Replace(@"\n", "&#xA;"))); // &#xA; is an XML newline character
            matches = true;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Section {0} replaced", sectionToReplace));
        }

        //if we have changed a section then save the file, otherwise don't bother
        if (matches)
        {
            //save the amended file. First transfer into an XmlDocument object, which converts the XML newline characters to genuine new lines 
            var newConfigFile = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            newConfigFile.LoadXml(configFile.ToString());
            newConfigFile.Save(fileToSearch);
            return 100; // Set ERRORLEVEL in batch file environment, 100 = matches.
        }
```

Given a replacementString value of

```
replacementString  = "<MenuPlugIns><!-- a comment -->\n<add key=\"xyz\" value=\"stuff\"/>"</MenuPlugIns>";
```

the resulting xml is

```
<MenuPlugIns>
<!-- a comment -->
<add key="xyz" value="stuff"/>
</MenuPlugIns>
```

which is exactly what I want. Thanks for the help.